# constexpr - What does "Evaluate value at compile time" mean exactly?

Tags: c++

```
#include <array>

int value1(int param) {
    return param * 2;
}

constexpr int value2(int param) {
    return param * 2;
}

int main() {
    const int i = 10;

    std::array<int, value1(i)> starr1 = {}; // 1
    std::array<int, value2(i)> starr2 = {}; // 2

    return 0;
}
```

`2` is okay, but `1` gives a compile error because `std::array` has to make static size array. `value2()` returns compile-time constant value because of `constexpr` keyword.

So, how does the compiler infer that `value2(i)` is compile-time constant? Does it call the function `value2()` while compiling?

```
const int value1(int param) {
    return param * 2;
}

int main() {
    const int i = 10;
    std::array<int, value1(i)> starr1 = {}; // 3

    return 0;
}

>>> error: call to non-constexpr function ‘const int value1(int)’
```

Also, `3` still tgives a compile error. Is `value1(i)` not compile-time constant even though `const` keyword is applied to the function `value1()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, how compiler infer `value2(i)` is compile-time constant?

It doesn't infer that. You state that explicitly when you annotate it with `constexpr`. It *might* infer that for functions *not* marked with `constexpr`, though. This still won't allow you to use their results in compile-time expressions, and is only used as an optimization strategy.

> Does it call the function `value2()` while compiling?

In a sense, yes. It's probably closer to interpreting it directly, since I don't think any compiler actually *compiles* that function for the purposes of executing it during the build. What matters is that it's able to establish its result before the entire program is built and ran, and that it can use that result to e.g. determine the size of your `array` when generating the code.

> Is `value1(i)` not compile constant even though `const` keyword is applied to the function `value1()`?

It's not. `const` only applies to the return type (and in this case, it's effectively useless), not the evaluation possibility in compile-time.

Comment: Side note - in C++20 this gets even more confusing with `consteval` being added, but that's out of scope for this question, I believe.